# Rename [tag:mountain] to [tag:mountains]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tagging

Shouldn't the tag [mountain](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain) be renamed to [mountains](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountains)? It sounds much better for me. I'd rather not say "I'm going to mountain" but "I"m going to mountains".

**disclaimer** I'm not native speaker, so my impression may be not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our general rule of thumb is to use the plural for noun tags, so I've renamed it accordingly.